# Open Percentage of SlidingDrawer in Android

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am trying to determine the "open" percentage of a SlidingDrawer in Android. It seems that the drawer only has *onOpen*, *onClose* and *onScroll* Listeners. OnScroll only provides methods for determining when scroll has ended and when scroll has begun.

TouchEvents won't work either because the SlidingDrawer can slide without being touched...

I tried grabbing the Animation of the SlidingDrawer using *getAnimation()* (and then somehow determining percentage based on that) but that returns null and so does *getLayoutAnimation()*.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, and I'm sure you don't care anymore, but someone else might. :)

I'm not entirely sure why you want a sliding drawer at all. It is likely easier and faster to write your own custom view that allows you to slide in and out, than to try to use sliding drawer. That way you will have way more control.

Another thought is to try getting the visible child rectangle of the sliding drawer from its container using [getChildVisibleRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildVisibleRect%28android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Point%29), and calculate the visible percentage using [getWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth%28%29) on the drawer. I'm not at all sure this will work. :)

Best of luck either way.

Comment: this isn't really an answer, but you make a great point which is that this should definitely be custom built, but I am surprised they didnt add an API for that... and yeah I don't care anymore haha